# How will my software behave if I broadcast with a certain capacity?

Tags: networking

I wanted to confirm something and will appreciate your help. Suppose we have three nodes called A,B and C. All are connected to a switch whose port supports 1 Gbps. Now suppose, Node's A network card is 100 Mbps while the the remaining have a 1 Gbps. Following are the constraints;

1) A can send B only with a maximum of 100 Mbps. 2) A can send C only with a maximum of 80 Mbps.

Now if I were to broadcast a 2 GB file;

1) It would reach B with approx 2.73 minutes. 2) It would reach C with approx 3.41 minutes.

Now even if I replace node A's network card with 1 Gbps with the same constraints, I would still get the same results. Have I got it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using something like UDP broadcast.

If you read / broadcast sequentially through a file, sustained broadcast traffic at a rate higher than C can process will loose some file components forever while going to C.

In this case you are limited by the least common denominator.  In the real world, C simply can't buffer 20Mbps of traffic for minutes at a time.

FYI, many people use 1024 bytes for a Kilobyte... using this assumption, the calculation in seconds is...

```
>>> (2*1024*1024*1024*8)/(80*1000*1000.0)
214.74836479999999
```

About 3.58 minutes

Replacing A's card with something faster than C's capacity will not help speed the transfer.

Also realize that the real world imposes encapsulation overhead (from Ethernet / IP / UDP headers), so you will never achieve line-rate data transfer rates, even between A and B.  You haven't told us what the protocols in question are, so that piece is still a question.

Comment: Yes...i'm using UDP broadcast. What I'm tring to verify is that if A were to broadcast this file (let's say @ 14:00), so both will receive it but at different times. B will receive it at 14:02 approx and C will receive it at 14:03 approx.

Comment: @AmaarBokhari, are A, B, and C in the same ethernet broadcast domain?  Is this a theoretical problem, or are you trying to solve some file transfer mechanics in the real world?

Comment: yes.They are in the same broadcast domain. Currently, Im investigating how it would work if I were to setup such a scenario. :)

Comment: @AmaarBokhari, A cannot broadcast to B and C at different rates, if both B and C listen on the same UDP port.  Again, you are limited by C's data transfer rates.

Comment: So this means that both B and C will receive the 2 GB file at 14:03 approx. Correct?

Comment: I'm transmitting it over a wired link. So to conclude, If a sender (Node A) has to broadcast a file, it will be limited (if any) by the node (node C) which has  less bandwidth as compared to the sender.